# Unable to logon when connecting to Oracle database with QGIS 3.20

Tags: qgis, oracle-spatial, connection

After I updated QGIS to 3.20 my old oracle connections doesn't work anymore.
I get the message "Unable to logon".
Under QGIS 3.16 everything works fine.

This is what I have read in the changelog to QGIS 3.18

"Feature: Oracle connection API
The QGIS API now includes QgsAbstractDatabaseProviderConnection for the Oracle provider.
This feature was funded by Metropole de Lille
This feature was developed by Julien Cabieces"

Can somebody give me an advice what that change do and what I can do?